# Finding the average value of a gradient in a certain region in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, climate

In one QGIS project, I have a few TIFFs. One is a black-to-white gradient map showing average precipitation. Each pixel has a value that signifies how much yearly precipitation it gets. I have another TIFF in the same project with many climate zones, each color signifying a different zone.

Would it be possible to find the average precipitation in each zone, like the average value on the gradient of each region? I'm not very good with QGIS.

Also I don't know how to code at all. I don't know if this is possible to do without having to code, but if it's necessary, would it be possible to make the instructions for simple or at least understandable for a beginner?

Answer (score 2):

No coding required. Zonal Statistics are designed to do this.

1. Show your raster. Make sure you know what the map's projection is. If it's lat/long, you are working in degrees (like this example), otherwise metres/feet/etc for projected units.

[image]

2. Set up a grid with **Vector - Research Tools - Grid** It can be rectangular, diamond or hexagonal.

[image]

This will give you a grid like this:

[image]

3. In the Processing Toolbox, look for Raster analysis - Zonal statistics

[image]

Select the mean as a statistic. It should create a layer like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!